# Actix web multiple configure register

Tags: rust, actix-web

when register multiple serviceConfig to configure in actix web only first one work, and I cant access to second configure registered.

```
HttpServer::new(move || {
    let cors = Cors::default()
        .allow_any_origin()
        .allow_any_method()
        .allow_any_header()
        .supports_credentials();
    App::new()
        .app_data(app_state.clone())
        .wrap(cors)
        .configure(roles::services::config)
        .configure(users::services::config)
})
.bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
.run()
.await
```

to access all registered configuration

Comment: I don't think you can call `configure` twice on the same scope, but you can pass different `serviceConfig` for different scopes, one for each though.

Comment: I try do .service(web::scope("/api").configure(users::services::config))
            .service(web::scope("/api").configure(roles::services::config)) but still only first one I define work, when send a request found in second register still give me not found.

Comment: web::scope("api") and web::scope("api") are still the same scope ! If you can't break this into scopes can't you merge your two serviceConfig and pass them at once ?

Comment: Make sure that the roles::services::config and users::services::config functions are defined and properly configured. These functions should contain the routing logic for each service. Also, no conflicts or overlapping endpoints.

Comment: @Peterrabbit Thanks you its works dont think the problem that have same scope :). have a nice day.